# Reuse identical parts across multiple buildouts

Tags: buildout

Is there a way to reuse parts across multiple buldouts? I've got several tools that I'd like to add to the buildout that don't change across buildouts. Here is an example case:

- Configured global buildout options such that download-cache=~/.buildout/downloads
- Buildout A needs cmake 2.8.4
- Buildout B needs cmake 2.8.4

One way to do this is to put the following in each of their configurations

```
[cmake]
recipe = zc.recipe.cmmi
url = http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.4.tar.gz
```

Since this doesn't change across the two buildouts, it would save more disc space if this could set up similarly to how eggs are cached. However, I cannot figure out a good way to do this. I don't think buildout was designed with this in mind.

---

Ideas:

- Is it possible to redistribute the cmake tarball as a python egg? Perhaps compile the tarball for different platforms and redistribute the binaries inside eggs?
- Another idea would to be have a recipe that can handle this kind of behavior. Maybe a recipe that wraps around other recipes and checks to see if the part is installed globally. Perhaps it would look like this:

```
[cmake]
recipe = my.recipe.reusuableparts
real-recipe = zc.recipe.cmmi
url = http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.4.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `zc.recipe.cmmi` recipe supports the usecase directly, but it's under-documented (the egg does contain [full documentation](http://zope3.pov.lt/trac/browser/zc.recipe.cmmi/trunk/src/zc/recipe/cmmi/shared.txt)). Simply set the `shared` option to the directory of your choice:

```
[cmake]
recipe = zc.recipe.cmmi
url = http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.4.tar.gz
shared = ~/shared-buildout-cmmi-builds/cmake/
```

or simply set it to `True` to put it in your buildout download cache:

```
[cmake]
recipe = zc.recipe.cmmi
url = http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.4.tar.gz
shared = True
```

It's up to individual recipes to support such sharing behaviour. I don't think a wrapping recipe is going to be easy seeing as buildout recipes can pretty much do anything.

Comment: That's not quite the question I am asking. I'm aware of how to do global configuration. What I want to do is use global configuration to reuse the location that cmake gets built in so that I have only one binary of cmake 2.8.4 and it is in, eg ~/.buildout/parts/cmake-2.8.4.tar.gz/

Comment: That works for what I need to do. Not all my shared parts are installed via cmmi, but I think I can easily work around that by making those parts be cmmi packages.